# Can DNS Caching Be Disabled for a Single Domain (BIND)?

Tags: dns, cache, bind

I have a BIND server (CentOS 6) on my local subnet handing my DNS requests. I also have a domain which points to my GoDaddy VPS. I would like to configure my BIND server so that it won't cache any requests for my domain. This is so when I update my domain's DNS records I don't have to flush the DNS cache on my server each time to see if my changes are working.

Basically each time I request my domain, I would like my BIND server to request the IP from the GoDaddy DNS servers. Requests for any other domain I would like it to cache normally.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Set the TTL on all your records to 5 seconds.  Or even 1 second if you like.  Then they won't be cached for very long at all.  Just don't use 0 for the TTL, it causes strange behavior with some resolver code.

Comment: Thats a good idea. I wonder if it is possible to do per-domain TTL. I'll look into this.

Comment: There is a default TTL per zone (per-domain as you say) that all record added to the zone inherit if they are not added with a specific TTL.

Answer (score 0):

If you have 9.3 or greater you can use rndc to flush the cache for a single
domain.

From DNS and Bind:

BIND 9.3.0 will support flushing all of the records attached to a particular
domain name with rndc flushname. For example:

```
rndc flushname google.com
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This would work but I'd have to run it each time, or set up a task to run it automatically, right? It wouldn't work automatically each time I request the domain?